# Why bool and int are not considered as a type error when str and float is required?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

When using [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) and [pyre-check](https://pyre-check.org/) to check type errors of the following code, neither produces an error:

```
from typing import List, Union

tlist: List[Union[str, float]] = [False, int(12)]
```

Just curious why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bool` is a subclass of `int`, which means they are both *natural numbers*. Natural numbers are a subset of real numbers, so they are acceptable where a float is acceptable.

That `int` is acceptable where `float` is specified is explicitly called out in [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower):

> Rather than requiring that users write `import numbers` and then use `numbers.Float` etc., this PEP proposes a straightforward shortcut that is almost as effective: when an argument is annotated as having type `float`, an argument of type `int` is acceptable[.]

- The `str` component in your `Union[]` doesn't play any role here; you could remove it and still the assignment would be accepted. It's purely the `float` type annotation that makes `12` and `False` acceptable values.
- The `int()` call is entirely redundant, the `12` literal syntax already produces an `int` object.