# In mypy why does boolean pass float type annotation

Tags: python, mypy

The example below returns a boolean instead of a float. This passes mypy and shows no errors in the PyCharm editor.

```
def add(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    return False
```

You can test this using the online mypy checker https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=92430212fc6c5e31b91f12154ef11998

How do I get mypy to complain here?

Comment: Also see [Why bool and int are not considered as a type error when str and float is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56099712/7851470)

Comment: Thanks, I can see that booleans are integers `isinstance(False, int) == True`. The duplicate question linked doesn't answer my question. Perhaps you can link your question as that does.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a gold badge in Python or mypy tag to do that. But we could ping @jonrsharpe and ask him to edit the duplicate target.

Comment: Added; thanks @Georgy