# Python 3.12 + VS Code (PyLance) not checking generic type as I would expect

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Is the following behaviour normal?

[image]

Hovering over `Prop` or `name` or `value` shows that types are identified correctly, so `value` is a `float`, but setting `value = True` doesn't seem to bother Pylance. [ok, see EDIT #3 below]

[System: Windows 11, Python 3.12.x, latest VS Code, settings seemingly configured reasonably]

**EDIT #1**
Ok, I don't do Python too often and I've fallen for this too many times. This is happening because booleans are castable as floats, (`float(True) == 1.0` is true), right? Now ok, I get that bools are not very strictly defined in python, but shouldn't a type checker in strict mode flag this? For clearly incompatible types, Pylance is working as expected, e.g.,:

[image]

**EDIT #2**

Here's the code as text (as requested in comments. Pictures were posted to highlight the presence or lack of type-checker flags):

```
class Prop[T]:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: T) -> None:
        self.name: str = name
        self.value: T = value
        self._type = type(value)

prop_noflag = Prop[float]('name', True)             # no flag
prop_flag   = Prop[float]('name', 'some_string')    # flag
```

**EDIT #3**
Ok, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099712/why-bool-and-int-are-not-considered-as-a-type-error-when-str-and-float-is-requir) and [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower). It's just that `bool <: int <: float`, which I find weak of course, but I understand is how the language itself works. But then what does the type checker do? Isn't the job of the type checker to protect the programmer from these types of 'errors'? No offense for the great work done, of course, just curious.

Comment: I meet the same problem even if I open the **type checking mode**, I've submitted [the issue to github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22655).

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Edited the original post for the code. Here's the error in the case of "EDIT":
`Argument of type "Literal['some_string']" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "float" in function "__init__"
  "Literal['some_string']" is incompatible with "float"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues`

Answer (score 0):

In the Python type system, a bool is a subtype of float, so a type checker will not report an error for your code sample.